# Sum over vector performing differently for nearly identical code

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, vector, stdvector

There seems to be a performance difference between these functions summing over an array and a vector when compiled with `g++` flag `-O3`:

```cpp
float sum1(float* v, int length) {
    float sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        sum += v[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

float sum2(std::vector<float> v) {
    return sum1(&v[0], v.size());
}
```

When calling `sum1` with e.g. an of length 100000 and `sum2` with a vector with same length and content, `sum2` ends up being approx. 10% slower than `sum1` in my tests.
Meaured run times are:

```
sum1: 0.279816 ms
sum2: 0.307811 ms
```

Now where does this overhead come from? Appended you also find the complete test code for the eventuality that I made a mistake there.

**[Update]** When calling by reference (`float sum2(std::vector<float>& v)`), a performance difference of approx. 3.7% is left, so this helps, but there is still some performance lost elsewhere?

**[Update2]** The rest seems to be statistically dominated, as seen with more iterations. Therefore, the only problem really is calling by reference!

---

Complete test code (compiled with flag `-O3` with `g++`, also tested with `clang++`):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

std::vector<float> fill_vector(int length) {
    std::vector<float> ret;

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        float r = static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX);
        ret.push_back(r);
    }

    return ret;
}

float sum1(float* v, int length) {
    float sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        sum += v[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

float sum2(std::vector<float> v) {
    return sum1(&v[0], v.size());
}

int main() {
    int iterations = 10000;
    int vector_size = 100000;

    srand(42);
    std::vector<float> v1 = fill_vector(vector_size);

    float* v2;
    v2 = &v1[0];

    std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> duration_sum1(0);
    for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        float res = sum1(v2, vector_size);
        auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        cout << "Result sum1: " << res << endl;
        duration_sum1 += t2 - t1;
    }
    duration_sum1 /= iterations;

    std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> duration_sum2(0);
    for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        float res = sum2(v1);
        auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        cout << "Result sum2: " << res << endl;
        duration_sum2 += t2 - t1;
    }
    duration_sum2 /= iterations;

    cout << "Durations:" << endl;
    cout << "sum1: " << duration_sum1.count() << " ms" << endl;
    cout << "sum2: " << duration_sum2.count() << " ms" << endl;
}
```

Comment: try changing the order of the tests... call sum2 before sum1

Comment: @user2717954 Tested, does not change the situation.

Comment: try changing `float sum2(std::vector<float>& v)`.

Comment: @2xB `float sum2(std::vector<float> v)` -- C++ has various ways of passing parameters.  Unfortunately you chose "by value", and not "by reference".

Comment: But the size of std::vector should be 3 * 8 bytes on a typical 64 bit x86. I shouldn't cause much overhead, and with the reference you have the overhead of dereferentiation as well

Comment: @PetokLorand Passing by value invokes a deep copy of the vector.

Comment: Can you try changing `v.size()` to passing `vector_size` in `sum2()`?

Comment: Aside: prefer `v.data()` to `&v[0]`. Also `float sum3(std::vector<float> & v) { return std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0f); }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the overhead comes from passing the vector.

Try passing a reference instead:

```
float sum2(std::vector<float>& v)
```

Comment: Oh, it copies the vector there. Great, that's it, thank you, and also @generic_opto_guy and @PaulMcKenzie!

Comment: If I call by reference, the performance difference left are 3.7%, so the majority of this issue here is indeed the call by value. Still, there is some performance lost elsewhere?

Comment: @2xB `sum2` calls `sum1`.  Maybe it is the setting up of the call that is causing the issue.

Comment: The remaining performance difference was seemingly purely statistically dominated. Therefore, calling by reference is indeed the one important difference here.

Comment: @2xB If this answer solved your issue (as it seems to be the case regarding your first comment), you may consider to accept it :)

Comment: @Fareanor Yes, I am not sure whether to accept this answer or the one by 眠りネロク, since his has more information but this one is more to the point and was posted earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `sum2()` accepts an `std::vector<float>` object *by value*:

```
float sum2(std::vector<float> v) {
    return sum1(&v[0], v.size());
}
```

In a scenario like this:

```
std::vector<float> vec;
// ...
sum2(vec); // copies vec
```

The parameter object `v` results in a copy initialization from the argument `vec` passed to `sum2()`. This can be an expensive operation, especially if the vector is large. If you are aiming at lower overhead associated with the call to `sum2()`, you have as options:

- Making `sum2()` accept a *reference* to `std::vector<float>` instead, i.e., `std::vector<float>&`:

  ```
  float sum2(std::vector<float>& v) {
     return sum1(&v[0], v.size());
  }
  ```

  In this case just a reference to the vector is passed to the function, not the whole vector, so no copy of the vector is created.
- Calling `sum2()` in a way so that its parameter object `v` is *move initialized* from the passed argument (as opposed to *copy initialized* – what you are currently doing) if you don't need the contents of `vec` anymore after the call to `sum2()`:

  ```
  sum2(std::move(vec)); // move instead of copy
  ```

Comment: `sum2(std::move(vec))` returns 0, so there is an issue with using that.

Comment: @2xB Because you call `sum2(std::move(vec))` in a loop. After the first iteration, `vec` is empty.

Comment: @2xB Your loop is just for benchmarking purposes. If you have a  vector that you are going to destroy just after calculating the sum of its elements, it's a good idea to move it instead of copying when passing it as an argument to `sum2()`.

Comment: For this case I find move to be wrong. There is no reson for `sum` to consum the input. It doesn't even modify the input.

Comment: @generic_opto_guy I'm just trying to expose the concept and explaining what's happening. If OP really wants `sum2()` to accept `std::vector<float>` *by value* and doesn't need the argument anymore, this approach will work for speeding up the call. Of course, there is no reason to consume the input, but if you don't need the vector afterwards, you don't really care.

Comment: @generic_opto_guy Note that the real issue is having `sum2()` accepting the vector by value. At the moment of calling `sum2()`, the programmer has to be very explicit about the move when the call could result in stealing the content of a named object, i.e., `std::move()` has to be used.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the already established answer of using a referenc to avoid a costly copy of the vector:

When using a reference you could go for a const reference.

You would need to change

```
float sum1(float* v, int length)
```

to

```
float sum1(const float* v, int length)
```

and

```
float sum2(std::vector<float> v)
```

to

```
float sum2(const std::vector<float>& v)
```

Using a reference means that you do not copy the vector, but this also allows `sum2` to make changes to the vector. Since your reason to use the reference is only for avoiding a copy, I think it would be good to state that `sum2` does not change the vector in it's interface.

The same logic for const applies to `sum1` and becomes no relevant, since a const vector only gives pointers to const.